# Nativescript transition animations are choppy on android device

Tags: nativescript

I've got a nativescript core app and I've set some animated transitions between pages like so:

```
var navigationOptions={
        moduleName:'views/achievement/achievement-page',
        animated: true,

            transition: {
                name: 'slideLeft',
                duration: 300,
                curve: 'easeInOut'
            },
    context:{
        id: item.id
    }
}
frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
```

I've been testing in iOS simulator, an iphone 6, and on my own Android device (Samsung S9+) and the animations are quite choppy on the adroid device, but they are nice and smooth on the iphone 6 and in the sim.

I'm not sure how I should really go about troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Very often it could be choppy if the new page sliding in contains heavy layout and a lot of UI components, data etc., You should try to load the data / render heavy layouts after navigation is completed, use [Page Events](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/page#page-events) for the same. If you still have issues, please share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks, I moved some of the loading to onNavigatedTo and that seemed to solve the choppy animation.